# make: *** [Makefile:204: shared/core_stream.lo] Error 1

Tags: php, sql-server, debian, unix, php7

Имеется Debian 10, 
Php 7.4.1, Nginx, php-fpm

Нужно подключиться к сервер MS SQL
Иду на офф сайт `https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=aps-pdw-2016#installing-the-drivers-on-debian-8-and-9`

Устанавливаю

```
sudo apt-get install -y curl apt-transport-https php7.4 php7.4-dev php7.4-xml
```

Далее устанавливаю ODBC драйвер

```
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=aps-pdw-2016
```

Выполняю далее

```
sudo pecl install sqlsrv
```

И при установке выдает такое

```
 g++ -std=c++11 -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootZdvETm/sqlsrv-5.6.1/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootZdvETm/sqlsrv-5.6.1/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv -I/usr/include/php/20190902 -I/usr/include/php/20190902/main -I/usr/include/php/20190902/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20190902/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext/date/lib -I/tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv/shared/ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -std=c++11 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -fstack-protector -c /tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv/shared/core_results.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o shared/.libs/core_results.o
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootZdvETm/sqlsrv-5.6.1/libtool --mode=compile g++ -std=c++11 -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootZdvETm/sqlsrv-5.6.1/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootZdvETm/sqlsrv-5.6.1/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv -I/usr/include/php/20190902 -I/usr/include/php/20190902/main -I/usr/include/php/20190902/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20190902/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext/date/lib -I/tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv/shared/  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -std=c++11 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -fstack-protector   -c /tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv/shared/core_stream.cpp -o shared/core_stream.lo
 g++ -std=c++11 -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootZdvETm/sqlsrv-5.6.1/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootZdvETm/sqlsrv-5.6.1/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv -I/usr/include/php/20190902 -I/usr/include/php/20190902/main -I/usr/include/php/20190902/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20190902/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext -I/usr/include/php/20190902/ext/date/lib -I/tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv/shared/ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -std=c++11 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -fstack-protector -c /tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv/shared/core_stream.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o shared/.libs/core_stream.o
/tmp/pear/temp/sqlsrv/shared/core_stream.cpp:209:1: error: invalid conversion from ‘size_t (*)(php_stream*, char*, size_t)’ {aka ‘long unsigned int (*)(_php_stream*, char*, long unsigned int)’} to ‘ssize_t (*)(php_stream*, char*, size_t)’ {aka ‘long int (*)(_php_stream*, char*, long unsigned int)’} [-fpermissive]
 };
 ^
make: *** [Makefile:204: shared/core_stream.lo] Error 1
```

Гуглил, ничего не нашел по данной ошибке. Можете помочь ?

Comment: Не верьте тому, что у них в основном мануале написано. Год назад ставил ODBC-дрова на Ubuntu 16.04 - неделю угробил на попытки. У них _местами_ встречаются _отдельные странички_, не связанные с основным текстом инструкции. Там и нашел ответ на свой вопрос и проставил. Но сам URL этой странички уже, увы, не нашел. Ищите поиском гугла - и пробуйте варанты. Чем могу, так сказать.

Comment: По каким запросам гуглили? а то я ищу, ничего найти не могу. Если по мануалу то сам ODBC ставится, а вот sqlsrv не ставится

Comment: Да не помню я деталей. Год назад было, помню - по мануалам на сайте не ставилось. Никак. Долго рыл, нашел на их сайте какое-то коротенькое решение, написанное "на коленке". На него ссылающихся страниц до этого не попадалось. Нашел в сохраненных ссылках https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-2017#installing-the-drivers-on-ubuntu-1604-1710-and-1804 и https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017. У меня стоят ODBC Driver 13 и 17. Может Вам поможет.

Comment: В том то и дело, что ODBC  драйвер встал корректно с первого раза, не устанавливается коннектор в виде расширения для php sqlsrv